# GOMAXPROCS already be 2, but program still hang

Tags: go

I already set runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2), but this program still hang when output some numbers. I can see high cpu used by this program(more than 100%), but I can't understand why the for loop goroutine can make my program not work.

go version is 1.4.2 on linux/amd64, and my pc has 4 CPUs.

here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"
import "time"

func forever() {
    for {
    }   
}

func show() {
    for number := 1; number < 999999; number++ {
        time.Sleep(1000)
        fmt.Println(number)
    }   
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    go show()
    go forever()
    for {
        time.Sleep(1000)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to ever have a busy loop that does nothing except burn CPU time. Not only does it consume an entire OS thread, but goroutines are cooperatively scheduled, and it will interfere with the runtime's goroutines. For example, on Go1.5 this will usually block the stop-the-world phase of the GC, (which you can test by setting `GOGC=off`).

To make this program run, you could insert a scheduling point in the for loop, but it would be better to remove it altogether.

```
func forever() {
    for {
        runtime.Gosched()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does time.Sleep() not block and reschedule?

Comment: I would expect forever to consume an os thread constantly, and main and show would fight over the remaining one. Not so in reality maybe?

Comment: @captncraig: time.Sleep is a scheduling point, but Gosched is more efficient if the sleeps are too short, since it does less.

Comment: @captncraig: The exact details change between releases, but in go1.5 it's blocked because the GC can't stop-the-world if the runtime has no way of forcing the `forever` loop to yield. The other goroutines do get multiplexed over the remaining thread (there are a few other goroutines in the runtime you don't directly interact with too).

Comment: @JimB Thanks. When I set GOGC=off I can see my program keep outputting numbers.

Answer (score 1):

From code, it looks like you want to print the number in for loop in go routine. In this case why not use channel to indicate when go routine is completed with for loop and accordingly exit the main function. Something like this

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "runtime"
import "time"


func show(result chan bool) {
    for number := 1; number < 999999; number++ {
        time.Sleep(1000)
        fmt.Println(number)
    }   
    result <- true
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)
    result := make(chan bool) 
    go show(result)
    <- result
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your answer is not I want. I just want to know why in this program goroutine can't work when there has 2 kernel threads.

Answer (score -1):

It's good to use `runtime.Gosched()`. 
But in golang, time.Duration is in Nanoseconds, so time.Sleep(1000) is nearly no sleep. mostly you consider it as milliseconds like things in Java. you can try

```
time.Sleep( 1000 * time.MilliSecond )
```